# How do I add image url with graph add in rdflib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, rdflib, foaf

I am using rdflib==4.1.2.
This is my code

```
>>> g=rdflib.Graph()
>>> s=rdflib.BNode()
>>> FOAF = rdflib.Namespace("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/")
>>> g.bind('foaf', FOAF)
>>> g.add((s, FOAF['img'],"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToZGEWvIBFgCiona6d74FtVthl4lkdJg3d61SGy-UCf4qFuDLD"))
```

I am getting this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 394, in add
    "Object %s must be an rdflib term" % (o,)
AssertionError: Object https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToZGEWvIBFgCiona6d74FtVthl4lkdJg3d61SGy-UCf4qFuDLD must be an rdflib term
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`Graph.add`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html?highlight=graph#module-rdflib.graph) expects a tuple with three nodes as can be seen in the [graph.py code](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/graph.py):

```
assert isinstance(o, Node)
```

you can use [`URIRef`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html?highlight=uriref#rdflib.term.URIRef) to convert your last parameter into one (see also the examples of the [documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html?highlight=graph#rdflib.graph.Graph)):

```
g.add((s, FOAF['img'],rdflib.URIRef("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToZGEWvIBFgCiona6d74FtVthl4lkdJg3d61SGy-UCf4qFuDLD")))
```